# Retrieving URL data when Content-Range is sent in PHP

Tags: php, curl

There's many options available for downloading a URL in PHP - but I'm stuck.

I've looked through all the ones I know, but none seem to pay attention to partial content headers.

I'm trying to retrieve a URL that gives the following header:
HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content
Content-Range:   bytes 0-100000/631723

As you can see it dishes out the file in 100,000 byte chunks.

Trouble is, when I use any method in PHP, ie file_get_contents, fopen, or even cURL, none of these continue on after receiving the first 100,000 bytes.

End result, I have a 100,000 byte file.

What I need is to get the PHP script to grab all the data, in the example above, all 631,723 bytes.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting a 206 Partial Content response, then you ***must*** have included a Range header field indicating the desired range in your request:

e.g.

```
GET /2390/2253727548_a413c88ab3_s.jpg HTTP/1.1
Host: farm3.static.flickr.com
Range: bytes=0-999
```

or there's a proxy somewhere that is breaking the requests into a series of range requests

**EDIT**

As a resolution, you might want to try sending a series of requests using the Get Range, then stitching them all together as you get each response

**EDIT 2**

If there is a proxy that's breaking the request so that you get a series of responses, you're probably only processing the first. You might be able to use the [CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) to register a callback that is called whenever each data response is received, and which could then manage the stitching back together of the various chunks.

Comment: file_get_contents and etc don't send that though, do they?

I have not explicitly got a range header anywhere in my code. I think the server is set up this way to dish out those headers regardless of your headers.

Comment: If the server is set up to do that when your request isn't specifying a range, then it's in contravention of RFC 2616

Comment: OK, I was hoping not to have to do it this way, but seems I will be forced to. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try sending it with `HTTP/1.0`, which did not define content range requests (and other caching and proxy tohuwabohu). Thus you ensure receiving the complete file.

If you want to use file_get_contents for that, then set the `protocol_version` parameter via `stream_context_create()`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Just given it a go, both with file_get_contents and using cURL and the CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION option. Both STILL get a content-range back. I think the server is set up to dish it out regardless as I say.

I have tried sending ranges, but it will send you back incorrect ranges. IE by default it dishes out in 100,000 byte pieces, if you request bytes 125000-160000 it will send you 100001-200001!

Comment: @Edward: Sounds like a pretty crude implementation. But obviously, you'll have to go the manual route then..

Comment: So much for backwards compatibility.